# My new DELL E2218HN has a yellow shade on it

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

Is this normal? I am not sure at all. I tried changing the color settings, but I just can't achieve the pure white which my old Dell IN2030M has. I got replacement for this monitor twice, but both of them have this tint. If I position my head slightly above the monitor, it looks pretty much white, but not as white as the previous monitor I had. Still slightly yellowish. I usually position my head just in the monitor's position:
[image]

Maybe a little higher than that, but not higher than the monitor.

I sit 50 cm away usually.

Is this normal for this new monitor (E2218HN) to be yellowish?

Comment: It doesn't matter for you. We could tell you it's normal and you still wouldn't like it.

Comment: "We could tell you it's normal and you still wouldn't like it". It's normal. Does that help? Probably not.

Comment: It needs **calibrating**. No monitor is going to be perfect out of the box. The generic .icc profile it installs is just that - generic. if you want accurate colour you need to calibrate. If you don't need accuracy but just something "nice" then it might be as simple as changing the colour temperature.

Comment: You can delete your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every monitor is different. Combine this with different settings in the monitor, and different types of panels and even different color profiles for different brands.

Some monitors have smaller viewing angles, where a wrong angle may distort the colors. If setting the brightness/contrast and color settings on the menu of your display does not give you the desired result, then your monitor is simply not capable of doing it better than that. It is even possible that buying two of the same brand monitors but slightly different model will give different shades of colors when put side by side.

So if you want the exact same image, you would be advised to get the exact same screen.

So long story short, its normal that your older DELL may be capable of producing whiter whites than your newer DELL monitor, especially if the technique is different.

Keep in mind that your older monitor may show things more white than it should, being actually inaccurate, and your newer model displays it closer to what it should be. Also, brightness and contrast and color profile will affect the display, as well as how much you tilt the display and how high your head is in comparison to the tilt.

Although it is logical, just for the sake of having a fully and complete answer:
light itself could also be a factor. When it comes to displays, they produce light, and light mixes really well with other light. This means that if a yellowish light shines on the display (think of an overlay lamp) the color will be more yellowish too. A monitor below a light will always be more yellow than a monitor near a window.

Comment: This answer basically boils down to "there's nothing you can do about it" which is patently untrue. Graphics professionals do it all the time, every display is individually calibrated. Admittedly they use an expensive hardware colorimeter, but you can still do it [less accurately] by eye.

Comment: @Tetsujin you can if the hardware supports it, which is what I say.